# Proving not an equivalence relation -the basic case

Tags: examples-counterexamples, formal-proofs

For the basic case Let $X=Y= \mathbb{R}$ and $R(X,Y)= \{(x,y) \in X \times Y : y=x^{2} \}$.

I know it's not symmetric, not reflexive, not transitive. How do I provide a counterexample that it's not an equivalence relation? I'm not entirely sure how to format this in the best way. Would providing a counter example be better ?

Comment: The answer is in the question : if you "know" one of these properties, it's enough: no need for a counterexample !

Comment: if you already know that it is not reflexive etc., then you can use the counterexamples for those to justiy that it is not equivalence.

Comment: Counter examples are certainly enough!